# Why is @ngrx/component tagged as experimental?

Tags: ngrx

I've been using @ngrx/component for about 3 years (if I recall correctly) and I've been super satisfied! I've also worked with it on environments with no zone and it's amazing.

I want to introduce it to my new colleagues though, but this tags stops me `This package is experimental and may change during development.`. Even though I have experience using this library on production, I cannot make a strong enough argument to convince them to use it cause of this tag.

Does anyone know why this library
is considered experimental still?